# javax.ejb.EJBException complex query

Tags: ejb

i have this complex query

```
select BORD_NUM + replace(B.NATUR_CODE,'I','E') + '/' + OP_NUM +' du ' + 
convert(char(10),OP_DATE,103) from OP O,  BORDEREAU B, EXERCICE E  where 
B.BORD_ANNEE=O.BORD_ANNEE and
B.BORD_N_SEQ=O.BORD_N_SEQ and
B.BORD_ANNEE=E.EXER_CODE and 
op_visa='Enc' and
FLAG_CLOTURE='Non'
```

i want to get a list from the result of this query an display in datatable in jsf page
i created a method to create this query to get a list from it an display to datatable in primefaces

here is my method :

```
 public List<Op> selectOp(){

return em.createQuery("select b.BORD_NUM + replace(b.NATUR_CODE,'I','E') + 
'/' + o.OP_NUM +' du ' + convert(char(10),OP_DATE,103) from OP o,  BORDEREAU 
b, EXERCICE e  where b.BORD_ANNEE=o.BORD_ANNEE and b.BORD_N_SEQ=o.BORD_N_SEQ 
and b.BORD_ANNEE=e.EXER_CODE and o.op_visa='Enc' and 
o.FLAG_CLOTURE='Non'").getResultList();
}
```

I called it in the managedBean Class and here is the code:

```
  public List<Op> getOp() {

    op=ejbFacade.selectOp();
    return op;
}
```

But when i run the jsf page i get this error :

```
 javax.ejb.EJBException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:752)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:702)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy271.selectOp(Unknown Source)
at services.__EJB31_Generated__OpFacade__Intf____Bean__.selectOp(Unknown Source)
at controller.OpController.getOp(OpController.java:81)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:1002)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:629)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:762)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeScrollBody(DataTableRenderer.java:375)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeScrollableTable(DataTableRenderer.java:322)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:217)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:84)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
  Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select b.BORD_NUM + replace(b.NATUR_CODE,'I','E') + '/' + o.OP_NUM +' du ' + convert(char(10),OP_DATE,103) from OP o,  BORDEREAU b, EXERCICE e  where b.BORD_ANNEE=o.BORD_ANNEE and b.BORD_N_SEQ=o.BORD_N_SEQ and b.BORD_ANNEE=e.EXER_CODE and o.op_visa='Enc' and o.FLAG_CLOTURE='Non']. 
 [20, 111] The right expression is not an arithmetic expression.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1616)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:456)
at services.OpFacade.selectOp(OpFacade.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
... 69 more
 Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
 Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select b.BORD_NUM + replace(b.NATUR_CODE,'I','E') + '/' + o.OP_NUM +' du ' + convert(char(10),OP_DATE,103) from OP o,  BORDEREAU b, EXERCICE e  where b.BORD_ANNEE=o.BORD_ANNEE and b.BORD_N_SEQ=o.BORD_N_SEQ and b.BORD_ANNEE=e.EXER_CODE and o.op_visa='Enc' and o.FLAG_CLOTURE='Non']. 
[20, 111] The right expression is not an arithmetic expression.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:334)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1614)
... 102 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should be a "native SQL" query.

You are calling [javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery("...")](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-), which expects to be passed a JPQL query - not pure SQL.

Try using [javax.persistence.EntityManager. createNativeQuery("...")](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-) instead.

Also, your query does not look like it will return `Op` objects, so you will need to pay some attention to that too.